# Python Unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I know the subject is not new, but I tried a lot of solutions, without success. I am using Python 2.7 (very not experimented user). My problem : I read a file :

```
my_file=open("file")
```

and then save the one line (which contains the word "pitié" into a variable, then I print it

```
line=my_file.readline()
print line
>> pitié
```

there, I got "pitié" as result.
But if I want to manipulate it, I see that my variable (string) contains some bytes :

```
line
>> 'piti\xc3\xa9'
```

My problem is when I need to do some operation to manipulate this string, I need to have the "é" character. For example to put it in a Flask template.
I tried some encode/decode operation, but I'm very confused. I get the usual

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x.. in position .: ordinal not in range(...)
```

What does the print function to give the right output ?

Thanks !

Comment: I see at least three issues in your question:

1. How to write/read Unicode to/from file in Python?
2. How does `repr(bytestring)` look like in Python? (and perhaps -- why).
3. Why do you get `UnicodeDecodeError` while doing *"some encode/decode operation"* (provide [complete minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead e.g., `b'piti\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')`)? **Could you narrow down your issue a bit?**

Comment: read [Unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of Unicode!  Your file is saved in UTF-8, a multibyte encoding, so characters outside the ASCII range of 0-127 require two or more bytes.  Read the file using the `codecs` or `io` module, and declare the encoding so it is read as a Unicode string, and non-ASCII codepoints up to 65535 will be a single codepoint.  Switch to Python 3.3+ and all Unicode codepoints  will be a single codepoint.

Note the first line of the example below declares the encoding of the *source file*.  It does not have to match the encoding of the data file, but is used so Python knows the encoding of the literal Unicode string `u'é'` in the source.

```
#coding: utf8
import io

with io.open('file',encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    line = my_file.readline()
print line
print repr(line)
print line.index(u'é')
```

Output:

```
pitié
u'piti\xe9'
4
```

Comment: As OP is using Python 2.7, shouldn't we prefer `io.open` over `codecs.open`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: we should.

Comment: Please, use "two or more bytes" instead of "two or more characters" (`u'\u00e9'.encode('utf-8')` -> `b'\xc3\xa9'`). There are Unicode characters that require more than one Unicode codepoint. Even `é` can be represented as two Unicode codepoints  `u'\u0065\u0301'` (NFD normalization form) i.e.,  *"all Unicode characters will be a single character."* is incorrect.

Comment: The pedants are out in force today :)

Comment: the closer the terms to the issue the more precise they should be e.g., if the question discusses prime numbers then you could use "characters" to describe bytes, Unicode codepoints, user-perceived characters (grapheme clusters), etc but if the question has [tag:unicode]; use more formal terms closer to Unicode standard and Python language spec. Don't create additional confusion by using a loose terminology; Unicode is complex enough by itself without your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing two different display methods: `print` shows you the pretty version, and just typing `line` gives you the raw "repr" version.  Nothing is wrong with the string.  If you write it to a file, it will be just as it was in your original input file.